# $f_n^\alpha(x) = n^\alpha x^n$ converges almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, pointwise-convergence

> In [0,1], with the Lebesgue measure and for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, I must show that $f_n^\alpha(x):=n^\alpha x^n$ converges almost everywhere in [0,1] and identify the limit.

It is clear to me that I've to build some set $E \subset [0,1]$ such that $f_n^\alpha$ converges in E and $|E^c|=0$, but I am struggling to see the limit and the construction of such a set.

Coud somone give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite it as (for $x\in(0,1)$)
$$
f_n^\alpha(x) = e^{\alpha \log(n)}\cdot e^{n\log(x)} = e^{\alpha \log(n) + n\log(x)}
$$
Now for $x\in(0,1)$, $\log(x) = -\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon >0$.
And the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \big(\alpha\log(n) -\varepsilon n\big)  = -\infty
$$
So $f_n^\alpha(x) \to 0$ for $x\in(0,1)$.
Now when $x=0$ you get that
$$f_n^\alpha(0) = n^\alpha \cdot 0 = 0$$

Lastly when $x=1$ you get that
$$f_n^\alpha(1) = n^\alpha\to\infty$$
meaning it diverges only when $x=1$.

Hence $f_n^\alpha$ converge almost everywhere.

Comment: thanks for your solution. I did something, at least, 4 times bigger, to reach the same solution. Your idea of using the exponencial was fantastic. 

How could I find the $\alpha$s for which $f_n^\alpha$ converges in $\mathcal{L}_p$?

Comment: Take an arbitrary $p\geq 1$ and compute the norm $\|f_n^\alpha\|_p^p$, it should be straight forward. Then see for which values of $\alpha$ the (limit of the) norm is finite / infinite :)

Comment: Just to make sure I am not wrong, because I do not feel very safe with it: $\|f\|_p^p = \frac{|n^{\alpha p}|}{np+1}$, so, it converges when $\alpha\leq 1/p$. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: @Anyway142 seems right at first glance :)